# SQL: Sort for start date if there is no end date

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I created a little SQL-fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cbee/1

I would like to sort these values:

```
INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`id`, `title`, `startdate`, `enddate`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Test 1', '2015-12-01 13:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'Test 2', '2015-12-01 14:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (3, 'Test 3', '2016-01-01 10:30:00', '2016-01-01 14:30:00'),
    (4, 'Test 4', '2016-01-01 09:30:00', '2016-01-01 15:30:00');
```

With SQL. The problem is: I would like to sort it according to the start date - if there is an end date, I would like to sort by end date.

The result should be:

```
    (2, 'Test 2', '2015-12-01 14:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (1, 'Test 1', '2015-12-01 13:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (4, 'Test 4', '2016-01-01 09:30:00', '2016-01-01 15:30:00');
    (3, 'Test 3', '2016-01-01 10:30:00', '2016-01-01 14:30:00'),
```

So the first items should be shown with descending order. All items with an end date should be displayed after (!) the items with no end date.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Use NULL for non-existing values, instead of that invalid date 0000-00-00. Then you can do `ORDER BY COALESCE(enddate, startdate) DESC`.

Comment: Hello, well, the CMS I'm using uses this `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as default. Unfortunately I can not change that.

Comment: Hopefully the CMS never switches to another DBMS backend, this is not a valid timestamp :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  title,
  startdate,
  enddate
FROM
  ForgeRock
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN enddate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   enddate DESC, 
   startdate DESC
```

This will display all items without an end date first, followed by all items with an end date.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below query given you don't have invalid date

```
SELECT
  title,
  startdate,
  enddate
FROM
  ForgeRock
order by startdate,enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

***`0000-00-00` is an invalid date*.**

You may need to change it as `null`.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  title,
  startdate,
  enddate
FROM
  ForgeRock
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN enddate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' /* or enddate IS NULL */
   THEN startdate END DESC,
   enddate DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of StartDate and End Date is varchar then you can use the below query -

```
   select * from ForgeRock
   order by 
     Case when enddate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
              Then '9999-12-31 00:00:00'
          Else enddate END desc, 
     startdate desc
```